# y value for createDataPartition in R

Tags: r, statistics

I can't figure out what exactly to put for the y function in the createDataPartition function. My understanding is that the partitioning is splitting the data into portions you specify, e.g. a 70/30 split for training and validation data, but I want to know if it matters which variable from the table you're using for the y variable.

Comment: Please read the documentation on the caret package: http://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html. If still unclear, rephrase question and try and post a code example people can use to help you

Comment: Okay, thank you. I read documentation elsewhere and it wasn't as clear but this helped clear it up. If I'm understanding right, it tries to keep the proportions from whatever variable you pick similar in both the training and testing datasets.